# Поиск с помощью locate

Tags: linux, bash, поиск, find

Возник такой вопрос. При поиске файлов с помощью `find` я могу указать глубину поиска. Например, только в ткущей папке указать параметр `"maxdepth 1"` и поиск не будет распространятся на другие директории в искомой.
А есть ли подобная возможность у команды `locate`? Ибо она находит нужные файлы, но также она находит и файлы во вложенных директориях, а там искать не надо.
Надеюсь, правильно донес мысль :)

Answer (score 0):

Достоинство locate, в том что поиск происходит быстро, это происходит за счет того, что поиск идет не в файловой системе, а базе данных, т.е. результат поиска можно отфильтровать регулярным выражением.
Это достоинство является и недостатком, информация в БД должна быть обновлена утилитой updatedb и на это требуется определённое время( вообще-то этим занимается служба). Если новые файлы и каталоги по каким-то причинам не были ещё проиндексированы в БД, то утилита locate их не сможет обнаружить.

Comment: Написано-то всё правильно, но как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Строки можно упорядочить , например | т.е. результат поиска можно отфильтровать регулярным выражением